# TensorFlow LSTM: confusion about batching and states

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

Looking at the official TensorFlow [RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) and [full code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py), I'm a little confused about how the data is divided over epochs. First, I don't understand the use of the state variable in the `run_epoch()` function. In the `main()` function, in the loop over epochs, we call:

```
def run_epoch(session, model, eval_op=None, verbose=False):
  """Runs the model on the given data."""
  start_time = time.time()
  costs = 0.0
  iters = 0
  state = session.run(model.initial_state)

  fetches = {
      "cost": model.cost,
      "final_state": model.final_state,
  }
  if eval_op is not None:
    fetches["eval_op"] = eval_op

  for step in range(model.input.epoch_size):
    feed_dict = {}
    for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
      feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
      feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

    vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)
    cost = vals["cost"]
    state = vals["final_state"]

    costs += cost
    iters += model.input.num_steps

    if verbose and step % (model.input.epoch_size // 10) == 10:
      print("%.3f perplexity: %.3f speed: %.0f wps" %
            (step * 1.0 / model.input.epoch_size, np.exp(costs / iters),
             iters * model.input.batch_size / (time.time() - start_time)))

  return np.exp(costs / iters)
```

What is the `state` variable and why are we enumerating and overriding the `model.initial_state` at every step?

Also, looking at the [reader.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py) file, the following splits the data:

```
def ptb_producer(raw_data, batch_size, num_steps, name=None):
  """Iterate on the raw PTB data.

  This chunks up raw_data into batches of examples and returns Tensors that
  are drawn from these batches.

  Args:
    raw_data: one of the raw data outputs from ptb_raw_data.
    batch_size: int, the batch size.
    num_steps: int, the number of unrolls.
    name: the name of this operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A pair of Tensors, each shaped [batch_size, num_steps]. The second element
    of the tuple is the same data time-shifted to the right by one.

  Raises:
    tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError: if batch_size or num_steps are too high.
  """
  with tf.name_scope(name, "PTBProducer", [raw_data, batch_size, num_steps]):
    raw_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(raw_data, name="raw_data", dtype=tf.int32)

    data_len = tf.size(raw_data)
    batch_len = data_len // batch_size
    data = tf.reshape(raw_data[0 : batch_size * batch_len],
                      [batch_size, batch_len])

    epoch_size = (batch_len - 1) // num_steps
    assertion = tf.assert_positive(
        epoch_size,
        message="epoch_size == 0, decrease batch_size or num_steps")
    with tf.control_dependencies([assertion]):
      epoch_size = tf.identity(epoch_size, name="epoch_size")

    i = tf.train.range_input_producer(epoch_size, shuffle=False).dequeue()
    x = tf.slice(data, [0, i * num_steps], [batch_size, num_steps])
    y = tf.slice(data, [0, i * num_steps + 1], [batch_size, num_steps])
    return x, y
```

Why do we split the data in batches and steps and mix the two? It's a little confusing. Why not just iterate through the whole dataset in batches or just steps?

Answer (score 0):

The two are totally different. The num_steps parameter controls the number of inputs after which backpropagation occurs. Splitting data in batches gives an efficient implementation by processing a larger piece of data in one go. It is bit confusing if you directly look at the batched input. Set batch_size to 1 and check how the input looks. This is like just using num_steps. Training the RNN will take longer.